# Creating File Path as a global variable to be used across two macros

Tags: vba, excel

I have two macros, Macro 1 and Macro 2 both of which are in an excel file that simply holds the macros. Macro 1 opens a File 1 using `FilePath1 = Application.GetOpenFilename()` and does some calculations. Macro 2 compares the calculation from File 1 to another file, File 2 which is opened using `FilePath2 = Application.GetOpenFilename()`.

I am having trouble referring to File 1 in Macro 2 because I need to activate the File 1 for it to do the comparison properly. It would be good to have the File Path of File 1 as a global variable that can be access across subroutines. How do I do that? I tried

```
Public FilePath1 As String
```

and then later in Macro 2

```
Workbooks(FilePath1).Activate
```

Comment: If you're not after lightning quick response times, how about using `SaveSetting` and `GetSetting` to store data in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings` area of the registry? This will be persistent though, so unless you want it stored forever on the machine, you'll want to wipe it when you're done.

Comment: So you are executing both macros in one go? If its a Workbook, then use a variable that you give over the second macro when calling it. Like `Macro2(wb as Workbook)`.

Comment: @CLR - this solution seems interesting, can you write it?

Comment: I could @Vityata , but to be honest a quick google of `vba GetSetting` will tell you how to use the command. It's a one liner to store it, and a one liner to read it.

Comment: @CLD - thanks, I was thinking its a bit more complicated, like making new registry entries or so.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Module containing your global variables and include this in the module:

```
Public Const FilePath1 As String = ".../..."
```

Then, you can use `FilePath1` anywhere in your code.